# Best way to train a deep learning model in AWS Sagemaker, when data (image data > 10000 images) lies on a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deep-learning, amazon-sagemaker

What is the best was to train a deep learning model on AWS Sagemaker when I have a huge image dataset stored on a AWS S3 bucket.
The Dataset shouldn't be downloaded to the EBS volume of the notebook instance.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/choose-the-best-data-source-for-your-amazon-sagemaker-training-job/) blog post covers options pros/cons, and other considerations.
The answer to your question depends on many other variables like Framework dataloader, read rate to saturate the GPU, the size of the files, total datset size, etc.